# Why my profile picture not visible to a person in my contact

Tags: whatsapp

Today morning my wife added few photos in her status, but I could not see that. Then we found that she also could not see my profile photo.

We both did not block each other, we both have our contacts saved in our phone. We both have configured 'my contacts' for privacy for both profile photo and status.

Then why it is happening? Any guess?

[image: these are the settings we both have in our phone] We made sure our number is not in those blocked list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There might be temporary network issue due to which the settings may get corrupted so if its due to that specific contact try to delete and readd else uninstall n reinstall this will clear the  existing corrupted cache.

Comment: Yeah. I checked that already. It seems all perfect. But still the problem exists. I tried restart both the phones also :(

Comment: just can you please share a screenshot of what you are facing actually

Comment: and did you check privacy settings profile pic might be set to nobody

Comment: Yes, I checked that too. All the three settings over there has set as 'My Contacts'. Issue could be from my side, otherwise the internet would have been buzzed by this time. I am trying to figure out that.

Comment: try to delete and again add your wifes contact and do refresh for both the contacts

Comment: I deleted the contacts from both the phones, then added back the contacts and restarted mobile. We both can see the photos and statuses of each other now. I am still surprised, why I could not see that particular status even after I did all the above steps. But I can see the status from the next time she posted.